# What does this piece of code do in Clojure.core.async?

Tags: clojure

This is piece of code from [The Beauty of Clojure](http://danboykis.com/posts/the-beauty-of-clojure/) I don't understand what **`alt!`** is doing here.

```
(defn listener [f ch]
  (let [stop-ch (chan)]
    (go-loop []
             (alt!
               stop-ch ([_] :no-op)
               ch      ([msg] (f msg) 
                              (recur))))
    {:listener ch :stop stop-ch}))

(defn stop-listener [{:keys [stop]}]
  (put! stop :stop))
```

Especially what does second argument to the **`alt!`** which is:

```
ch     ([msg] (f msg)
              (recur))
```

does?

And does **`go-loop`** mean that after **`listener`** function is called it would wait indefinitely to receive values?

Comment: You might want to see [core.async presentation](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/clojure-core-async)

Answer (score 0):

The go loop alt! will execute either block depending on which channel has a message.

You’ll notice that the stop-ch does not recur and therefore after receiving a stop, the go loop will end.

If something is received on the listener channel, it is processed by the function f. The recur then takes us back to the start of the go loop, where alt! will wait for further messages on either the listener or the stop channel.

The listener structure created is a map of two channels - put things into listener and they will be f’ed, put anything onto the stop and the listener will stop. This final detail is then abstracted away for the user by the stop-listener fn.

This whole thing is in essence just a simple adaptor between a core.async channel and a function, with clean up logic.

*And does go-loop mean that after listener function is called it would wait indefinitely to receive values?*

No. Calling listener won’t block the flow of control. The go loop created will “block” until it receives input on one of the channels, however. I’m using quotes because this isn’t a blocked thread - I really recommend you take a look at some of the basic core.async presentations once you’ve had a play at the REPL. Once you can tie the behaviour up to the theory it’s quite straightforward.

Comment: Kindly elaborate last paragraph a bit? About adapter.

Comment: You have a (side-effecting, presumably) function. You have a channel. This listener pattern is an adaptor, in that it converts incoming messages on a channel into calls of your function. Does that help? I’m using adaptor here in the sense of the GoF adapter pattern - although obviously patterns from OO look different in LISP.